# Different SupportMapFragment instances

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-maps-v2, supportmapfragment

I am using the Google Maps Android API v2 in an app that uses fragments.

In the OnCreate of fragments that uses the map I have:

```
FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
fragment = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
if (fragment == null) {
    fragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.map, fragment);
    transaction.commit();
}
Log.e("app", "Fragment: " + fragment);
```

If I creates a fragment with a map I get:

```
06-19 15:12:10.839: E/app(10523): Fragment: SupportMapFragment{42238748 id=0x7f06004d}
```

If I from here directly creates a new fragment and switch to this (with fragmentManager.replace) I get

```
06-19 15:12:19.968: E/app(10523): Fragment: SupportMapFragment{42238748 #0 id=0x7f06004d}
```

If I go to a fragment that has no map view and then go back to a fragment with a map I get:

```
06-19 15:12:19.968: E/app(10523): Fragment: SupportMapFragment{42238748 id=0x7f06004d}
```

So the point is sometimes when the OnCreate executes it gets the "id=0x7f06004d" and sometimes the "#0 id=0x7f06004d".

Can anyone enlighten me what the "#0" indicates? As I would expect the same instance all the time.